# how to make reset button automatically play again when its clicked?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

> another thing is the timer for seekBar its for the duration of the audio file the issue within it is that the audio file do (mini) stop every 1 sec so how to make seek bar update itself every second without doing any stops

```
        seekBar2.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override

        public void run() {
            seekBar2.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
        }
    },0,1000);
    public void reset(View v) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this to Reset Your mediaPlayer

```
public void reset(View v) {
       mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
       mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

> Try this to update your seekbar

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
//you have to  update Seekbar on UI thread
Your.Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            seekBar2.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

> and whenyou need to update the `MediaPlayer`'s position while user drag your `SeekBar` use below code

```
seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: thanks Nilesh but the seekBar still doesn't work as it should be the problem now its like repeating the same word for more than once

Comment: can you explain more about it @Beginner

Comment: I have copied the code and the result is that the audio file when it plays every 1 sec it repeats it self more than once